# How to move histogram values of an image according to another image's histogram values

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, histogram

I am working on a computer vision project. The dataset I use had been gathered by many different tools. So histogram of these image can be vary. So I am trying to decrease differences of these images so CNN model can learn and achieve higher accuracy. I hope so...

I also used `histogram equalize` but it didn't increase accuracy. So I need an method which move `image 2` histogram values to `image 1` histogram values to make two of them similar.

Also I google for a method to convert two histograms to normal distribution but I couldn't find. I mean if there is one, a method converge both histogram each other is welcome.

And also if there is a way to change histogram values manually efficiently will be usefull.

However, here 2 histograms of 2 images which are taken from different tools.

image 1

[image]

image 2

[image]

Comment: heard of "earth mover's distance" and similar operations? -- in general, you calculate the cumulative distributions, which helps in the mapping.

Comment: I didnt. I research it but couldn't understand how to use to solve the problem. Can you explain it more?

Also, can you write other operations? I dont know them at all.

Comment: See my Imagemagick scripts, redist and histmatch, at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick.  The first tries to make the image's histogram into a normal (Gaussian or bell-shape) distribtution. The second tries to make one image's histogram look like the other image's histogram.  Christoph Rackwitz is correct. You work with the cumulative histograms. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching and https://automaticaddison.com/difference-between-histogram-equalization-and-histogram-matching/. Search Google for more links